# Why does Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL lead to an option of WhatsApp in chooser dialog when WhatsApp is NOT a mailing app?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("email/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]"foo@gmail.com"});
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Mail"));
```

In this chooser dialog, I get option like 'GMail' and it is working perfectly fine. When I select Gmail App it fills the "To" (recipients) as `"foo@gmail.com"`, as is desired.

My question is why this chooser also shows 'WhatsApp' when WhatsApp **CANNOT** handle such an intent. Even if I select WhatsApp and try to send a message, it does nothing (because WhatsApp cannot handle intent to fill "To" like email apps can). The App does not crash.

Now I understand that WhatsApp might be listening to this intent because the type includes 'text', but if I try using :

```
intent.setType("email");
```

The chooser dialog says 'there is no app to perform this function'.

Now, is this a fault from WhatsApp developers? Or am I using the mail sending intent the wrong way(and how should I use it then)?

I hope I have made myself clear, please ask anything else needed to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this chooser dialog, I get option like 'GMail' and it is working perfectly fine.

That means that Gmail must support a `*/*` wildcard pattern for the MIME type, as `email/text` is not a valid MIME type.

> My question is why this chooser also shows 'WhatsApp' when WhatsApp CANNOT handle such an intent

The developers of WhatsApp app believe that they can handle such an `Intent`.

> Even if I select WhatsApp and try to send a message, it does nothing (because WhatsApp cannot handle intent to fill "To" like email apps can).

The fact that WhatsApp ignores `EXTRA_EMAIL` is perfectly reasonable. `ACTION_SEND` is a *request*, not a command. `EXTRA_EMAIL` is a *suggestion*, not a command. For example, there is no requirement for Gmail to pay any attention to `EXTRA_EMAIL` in its `ACTION_SEND` implementation. It happens to do so, but do not assume that all `ACTION_SEND` implementations will pay attention to `EXTRA_EMAIL`.

> if I try using `intent.setType("email");` The chooser dialog says 'there is no app to perform this function'.

That is because `email` does not have the structure of a MIME type.

> Or Am I using the mail sending intent the wrong way(and how should I use it then)?

There is no "mail sending intent" in Android.

Your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is lacking anything to send, as it has neither `EXTRA_TEXT` nor `EXTRA_STREAM`. As a result, *lots* of `ACTION_SEND`-capable activities will not do anything useful with your `Intent`.

[The JavaDocs for `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) is a bit difficult to read, but it explains what an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is for and how to set one up. The documentation also has [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail) may also be of use.